# How can I automate this using Pandas grouping function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes as below;

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'A','B','B','C','C'],
                   'Col1': ['a1','a2','','','',''],
                   'Col2': ['', '', 'b1','b2','',''],
                   'Col3': ['', '', '','','c1','c2'],
                   'Col4': ['a11','a12','','','',''],
                   'Col5': ['', '', 'b11','b12','',''],
                   'Col6': ['', '', '','','c11','c12']
                  }
                )

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'A','B','B','C','C'],
                   'Field': ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6']
                  }
                )
df2
```

I'm trying to combine the two dataframes to get an output like below; Any help?

[image]

Output format2 :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with remove rows with empty strings by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), last sorting by `Group` column by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = (df1.melt('Group', 
              value_name='Values', 
              var_name='Field')
        .query('Values != ""')
        .sort_values('Group', ignore_index=True))
print (df)
   Group Field Values
0      A  Col1     a1
1      A  Col1     a2
2      A  Col4    a11
3      A  Col4    a12
4      B  Col2     b1
5      B  Col2     b2
6      B  Col5    b11
7      B  Col5    b12
8      C  Col3     c1
9      C  Col3     c2
10     C  Col6    c11
11     C  Col6    c12
```

If empty strings are missing values `NaN`s use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = (df1.melt('Group', 
              value_name='Values', 
              var_name='Field')
        .dropna(subset=['Values'])
        .sort_values('Group', ignore_index=True))
```

Last for merge both DataFrames:

```
df = df.merge(df2, on=['Group','Field'])
print (df)
  Group Field Values
0     A  Col1     a1
1     A  Col1     a2
2     C  Col6    c11
3     C  Col6    c12
```

EDIT: Because values in `Group` are duplicated use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex`, then replace empty strings to missing values, so possible create expected ouput by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and  [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df1.set_index([df1.groupby('Group').cumcount(), 'Group'])
         .replace('',np.nan)
         .stack()
         .unstack(0)
         .rename(columns = lambda x: f'Value{x+1}')
         .rename_axis(['Group','Field'])
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  Group Field Value1 Value2
0     A  Col1     a1     a2
1     A  Col4    a11    a12
2     B  Col2     b1     b2
3     B  Col5    b11    b12
4     C  Col3     c1     c2
5     C  Col6    c11    c12
```

Comment: It works!! However, in case of huge datasets, the number of rows are exceeding the excel limit thereby difficult to read the complete data. Can the output be arranged in column to reduce rows? Added the output format 2 to the question

Comment: @Osceria I am confused, output2 is not same like source dataframe?

Comment: My bad!! pasted the wrong image, corrected it now

Comment: @Osceria - answer was edited.